# Setting the Response Header Using Express Node

Tags: node.js, express

I am using the following code to set the response header:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/",function(req,res){

  res.header('Content-Type','application/json');

  var task = { title :"Do the grocery" }
  res.send(JSON.stringify(task));
});
```

When I see in my response in Google Chrome I don't see the response header "Content-Type" being set. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You might be looking for `res.set('Content-Type','application/json')`

Answer (score 2):

That's not a method afaik, should be:

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

As a sidenote, if you call `res.json()` you can just pass it an object and it'll json stringify it for you.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about res.send(). Nice! Still I see the following headers in chrome: HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
X-Powered-By: Express
ETag: W/"38-H2y9q1ML8w8H3Zyxg0gEyfGPVuk"
Date: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 18:06:34 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: That is half true. you need to use the `.json()` method instead of `.send()`